# Semantic nesting error from underscores with `listings` while `syntax` is loaded

Tags: errors, listings

I use XeLaTeX and have TeXLive 2015 installed.

I want to use both the `listings` package for printing code and the `syntax` package for printing grammars. For code, I also want to expand certain symbols als literate mathematical strings, for example I want `N0` to yield ‘N₀’, consuming two characters. To this end, one may use the `literate` facility of the `listings` package, see its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Now, here’s my problem: Running `xelatex` on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
    listings,
%   syntax,
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
    literate={N0}{{$N$}{$_0$}} 2
}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
    N0 $N_0$
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

yields a result as expected, but uncommenting the line `%   syntax,` to load the `syntax` package, will give a semantic nesting error on compiling:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500].
<recently read> {

l.16 ^^IN0
           $N_0$
No pages of output.
```

I found out that the culprit is the mathematical underscore in `literate={N0}{{$N$}{$_0$}} 2`, and only in the `literate` part. Replacing this line by `literate={N0}{{$N$}{$0$}} 2` (i.e. removing the underscore) will let `xelatex` compile again. Note that there still is a mathematical underscore in `$N_0$` inside of the listing environment.

What is going on? Can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, don't use the `minimal` class for testing, see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

You have two ways for avoiding the infinite loop: either doing `\lstset` in the preamble or using `\sb` instead of `_`.

### First way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
    fontspec,
    unicode-math,
    listings,
    syntax,
}

\lstset{
    literate={N0}{{$ℕ$}{$_0$}}2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
    N0 $ℕ_0$
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

### Second way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
    fontspec,
    unicode-math,
    listings,
    syntax,
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
    literate={N0}{{$ℕ$}{$\sb0$}}2
}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
    N0 $ℕ_0$
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

### Output for both

[image]

Comment: This is, of course, already a completely satisfactory answer. I’m going with the second way. Thanks! It might be nice for some to actually see a hint for *why* the problem only occurs on loading the `syntax` package. I’m kinda curious myself, though I’m not sure I’ll understand it. But as said, I’m perfectly content either way.

Comment: @k.stm The reason is quite involved: the `syntax` package makes `_` into an active character at begin document, but for its purposes `listings` considers it with its standard category code when evaluating options. Chaos ensues: groups are opened in series and the semantic nest size is exhausted, but it's essentially an infinite loop.